# How to get a double to stop giving really long decimal places?

Tags: java, function, methods, int, double

For example here, this calculateVolume() uses doubles

```
private double myRadius;
private double myVolume;
private double mySurfaceArea;
private final static double pi = 3.14;


public double calculateVolume(){
    myVolume = (4.0/3)*pi*(Math.pow(myRadius,3));
    return myVolume;
}
```

and when I give myRadius a value of 6, it returns 904.3199999999999. Is there any way to just make it 904.32?

Comment: Use a [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: Either use a `NumberFormat` or use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class. In the method [`setScale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) you can define the precission you need:

```
double volume = calculateVolume();
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(volume).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(decimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat to do this.

```
double d= 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String s = df.format(d);
```